# Why do some functions need 'function' declared before the function name?

Tags: javascript, function

I am used to writing functions like this:

```
myFunction() {
   // do something cool
};
```

But recently I have an instance where the function only works if I declare `function` before the function name:

```
function myFunction() {
   // do something cool
};
```

What causes the need for a function to be declared like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first function declaration would only work in the objects and classes. If you want to declare a function outside of an object or a class then you have to use either `function` keyword or an arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

```
myFunction() {
   // do something cool
};
```

isn't valid javascript do begin with.

```
function myFunction(){/*body*/}

var myFunction = function(){}

var myFunction = ()=>{};

var myFunction = new Function('/*body*/');
```

are valid function declarations.